# Views overlapping eachother in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, ios7, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I'm trying to make a MVC application in Xamarin Studio for iPhone. I have a `NavigationBar` and I've added a `NavigationItemSetLeftBarButtonItem()` which toggles the sidebar from the [Flyout Navigation](https://components.xamarin.com/view/flyoutnavigation) component. Works pretty well except for this, see image below:

[image: Attached screenshot]

As you can see, the "sidebar" is going beneath the NavigationBar. How can I push it down so that it looks like this example image:
[image]

**[DashboardScreen.cs code](https://gist.github.com/jackbillstrom/1ae20bca3057d90503c5)**

Answer (score 0):

You should set top margin for you `NavigationTableView`, so:

```
var navigation = new FlyoutNavigationController(); //the place where you init your side menu
navigation.NavigationTableView.Frame = new RectangleF(
                                           navigation.NavigationTableView.Frame.X,
                                           65,
                                           navigation.NavigationTableView.Frame.Width,
                                           navigation.NavigationTableView.Frame.Height - 65);
```

Comment: No differance at all, wierd.

Comment: Why isn't your snippet acting like it should @choper?

Comment: Looked on the sorces of the `FlyoutNavigation`, on the `ViewWillAppear` they reset the position to the zero, so the only suggestion that I can provide it's to download the sources from github - https://github.com/Clancey/FlyoutNavigation - and make the changes that you need (top margin actually)

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the source of how you constructed your views its hard to tell. But my guess would be you have everything nested in a UINavigationController which most likely isn't what you want. It appears this way because your content is moved out and the nav bar has not.  What you should do is...

```
window.RootViewController = flyout;
flyout.ViewControllers = new []{
    new UINavigationController(vc1),
    new UINavigationController(vc2),
    new UINavigationController(vc3),
```

};

Answer (score 0):

try setting the Translucent-Property of the NavigationController.NavigationBar to false.
This should solve the problem.